# Haskell Recursive 'sum' Function

Tags: list, function, haskell, recursion

I find it really difficult to understand the mechanics of the following recursive function:

```
sums (x:y:ys) = x:sums(x + y : ys)
sums xs = xs

sums ([0..4])

Output:
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
```

What exactly happens in this line?:

```
x:sums(x + y : ys)
```

I would say that before the program can append the 'x' to the list, the function sum(x + y : ys) has to be executed first. But in that case, 'x' would be appended to the list only once - at the end of the recursion loop - which wouldn't result in the given output... so where are the flaws in my logic?

My follow-up question: how should I look at/treat recursive functions in a logical way, that will (hopefully) lead me to an 'aha-erlebnis'?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: "has to be executed first" -- why do you care about that? In Haskell, we do not care much about execution order, focusing on the returned result instead. Even when reading the above code operationally, I actually follow the opposite direction: `x : sums (x+y : ys)` generates `x` in the output list first, and then proceeds by evaluating `sums (x+y : ys)` (which will produce the rest of the list).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can understand Haskell code by stepwise reduction. Maybe the following example reduction sequence helps with your aha.

(A Haskell implementation actually does something related to such reduction steps, but maybe in a different order. You get the same end result, though).

In this example, you start with:

```
sums [0..4]
```

Expand the `[0..4]` notation a bit:

```
sums (0 : 1 : [2..4])
```

Now we see that the first equation of `sums` matches, with `x = 0`, `y = 1`, and `ys = [2..4]`. So we get:

```
0 : sums (0 + 1 : [2..4])
```

We can compute `0 + 1`:

```
0 : sums (1 : [2..4])
```

And expand `[2..4]` a bit:

```
0 : sums (1 : 2 : [3..4])
```

Now we see that the first equation of `sums` matches again, this time with `x = 1`, `y = 2`, and `ys = [3..4]`. So we get:

```
0 : 1 : sums (1 + 2 : [3..4])
```

We can compute `1 + 2`:

```
0 : 1 : sums (3 : [3..4])
```

And expand `[3..4]` a bit:

```
0 : 1 : sums (3 : 3 : [4..4])
```

Now we see that the first equation of `sums` matches again, this time with `x = 3`, `y = 3`, and `ys = [4..4]`. So we get:

```
0 : 1 : 3 : sums (3 + 3 : [4..4])
```

We can compute `3 + 3`:

```
0 : 1 : 3 : sums (6 : [4..4])
```

And expand `[4..4]`:

```
0 : 1 : 3 : sums (6 : 4 : [])
```

Now we see that the first equation of `sums` matches again, this time with `x = 6`, `y = 4`, and `ys = []`. So we get:

```
0 : 1 : 3 : 6 : sums (6 + 4 : [])
```

We can compute `6 + 4`:

```
0 : 1 : 3 : 6 : sums (10 : [])
```

This time, the first equation for `sums` doesn't match. But the second equation matches. So we get:

```
0 : 1 : 3 : 6 : 10 : []
```

This is the observed output `[0, 1, 3, 6, 10]`.

Answer (score 3):

This is no different than recursion in any other langauge. When `sums [0..4]` (the parentheses are unnecessary) is first called, `x==0`, `y==1`, and `ys == [2..4]`. Thus, the return value is a new list created from `0` and `sums [1..4]`.

In a strict language, the recursive call would complete before finally creating the new list. Since Haskell is lazy, a list starting with 0 and continuing with a *promise* to evaluate `sums [1..4]` is returned. The recursive call won't actually be evaluated until someone actually tries to access the tail of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could notice that

```
sums (x:y:ys) =  x:sums(x + y : ys)
```

is equivalent to

```
sums (x:y:z:ys) = x:x+y:sums(x+y+z : ys)
sums (x:y:ys) = x:sums(x + y : ys)
```

and (with more than 2 items) is also equivalent to

```
sums (x:y:z: w: ys) = x:x+y:x+y+z:sums(x+y+z +w: ys)
sums (x:y:z:ys) = x:x+y:sums(x+y+z : ys)
sums (x:y:ys) = x:sums(x + y : ys)
```

so by induction you have that

```
sums(1:2:3:4 :[])
```

is equal to

```
1 : 1 + 2 : 1 + 2 + 3 : 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 : []
```

Based on the above you can also predict that with

```
fact(x:y:ys) = x: fact(x * y : ys)
fact(xs) = xs
```

then

```
fact([1..4])
```

is

```
1:1*2:1*2*3:1*2*3*4:[]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two equation that define the function `sums`. Keep rewriting an expression that involves `sums` using the first equation that matches the argument, or other suitable equations (like 1+2=3).

```
sums [0..4] = 
    -- by syntactic sugar
sums (0:1:2:3:4:[]) = 
    -- by eq. 1, x=0,y=1,ys=2:3:4:[]
0 : sums ((0+1) : 2 : 3:4:[]) = 
    -- by addition 
0 : sums (1 : 2 : 3:4:[]) = 
    -- by eq. 1, x=1, y=2, ys=3:4:[]
0 : 1 : sums ((1+2) : 3 : 4:[]) =
    -- by addition 
0 : 1 : sums (3 : 3 : 4:[]) =
    -- by eq. 1, x=3, y=3, ys=4:[]
0 : 1 : 3 : sums ((3+3) : 4 : []) = 
    -- by addition
0 : 1 : 3 : sums (6 : 4 : []) = 
    -- by eq. 1, x=6, y=4, ys=[]
0 : 1 : 3 : 6 : sums ((6+4):[]) = 
    -- by addition
0 : 1 : 3 : 6 : sums (10:[]) = 
    -- by eq  2,xs=(10:[]) 
0 : 1 : 3 : 6 : 10 : [] = 
    -- by syntactic sugar
[0,1,3,6,10]
```